# Select sheet command doesn't work in a corrupted excel file

Tags: excel, vba, select

I get an excel (xlsx) file with two sheets everyday from our business partner. I would like to analyze this data but in my macro when

Sheets(2).Select

I get Run-time error '1004'

I tried with the sheet name, then I add a new sheet but I can't seletc that one either with macro. I recorded a macro 'select sheet' then I ran that macro and the same error message. Then I opened the file with

_corruptload:=XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile

but it didn't help

Comment: If you are doing this with a macro then there is no need to use `Select`. If you provide your code and possibly a snapshot of your workbook, it might help to resolve your problem

Comment: Like @Zac suggested you should avoid working with `Select` here is how: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) but you can't select a worksheet unless you have as active workbook the workbook containing it, so you should first focus that workbook.

Comment: if i just use this basic sub, i get error message

Sub data()

Sheets(1).Select
    
End Sub

Comment: @Damian: Not sure that's true Damian.. i.e. if my active workbook is `WB1` and I want reference `Sheet1` from `WB2`, all I have to do is: `Workbooks("WB2").Worksheets("Sheet1")`. I could also use something lik: `With Workbooks("WB2").Worksheets("Sheet1")` I don't ever need to activate the WB2

Comment: @Zac of course, but if you want to `Select` `Sheet1` you must activate `WB2` that's for sure.

Comment: I know there are exceptions to rules but my question would be: why is OP attempting to select a sheet in the first place? More often then not it's because people don't realise that they don't have to and infect it's more efficient just to reference a sheet

Comment: Does the error occur all the time or just with corrupt files?

Comment: Are there 2 (or more) sheets in the workbook? Try opening the file with Excel, start IDE with Alt+F11, and issue the `Sheets(2).Select` command in the immediate window. What happens then?

Comment: @AcsErno yes, only with corrupt file. in every file there are exactly 2 sheets. When I use immediate windows, it works but then the macro fails again.

Comment: You need to post your code and possibly a screenshot of your project window.  It is not giving you a `Subscript out of range` which would indicate it doesn't exist or recognize it.  There may be other things involved.

Comment: Would also help to know where you are running your macro from, presumably not from the .xlsx file that you receive, unless you are pasting the code into the workbook when received.

Comment: If the second sheet is hidden this would occur. Try using the name of the sheet rather than the index: Sheets("mysheet").activate ought to work